# How to get Cognito Identityi Id in custom authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I need to know who sends request in AWS custom authorizer lambda function. I have an authorizationToken in lambda function. How to get cognito user id in AWS custom authorizer lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly what the **authorizationToken** is. I assume it is an ID token you get from signing in using a Cognito identity pool. If so, you can use the Cognito Identity GetID API to get the identity id of the user. See [this](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cognito-identity.html#CognitoIdentity.Client.get_id) link for boto3 example. You can implement the same in other languages also. You would need to pass the account id, the identity pool being used & a login map.